# GRANT/REVOKE on functions

Tags: postgresql, permissions

I am using the `has_function_privilege`, to check and see if a certain user can access a function in my database. However, if I use `REVOKE` to revoke access, `has_function_privilege` still returns true:

```
db=> revoke execute on function getid(text,text)  from user1;
REVOKE
db=> select has_function_privilege('user1', 'getid(text, text)', 'execute');
 has_function_privilege 
------------------------
 t
(1 row)
```

I am using PostgreSQL 9.2.3 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably because `public` has execute privilege on your function (it's the default).

Try this:

```
revoke execute on function getid(text,text)  from public;
```

and recheck the result of `has_function_privilege`.

For `public` to not get this privilege on newly created functions, you may change the default with:

```
ALTER default privileges revoke execute on functions from public;
```